# C++ return by reference what are the effects?

Tags: c++, reference, pass-by-reference, return-by-reference

Take the following code, where a function returns by reference:

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int & myFunction(int & input) {
    return input;
}

int main() {
    int x;
    int y = 10;
    x = myFunction(y);
    printf("x is %d\n",x); // x is 10
    printf("y is %d\n",y); // y is 10
    x = 20;
    printf("x is %d\n",x); // x is 20
    printf("y is %d\n",y); // y is 10
    return 0;
}
```

Except the obvious pitfall of returning a reference to a local variable of the function (which is not the case here), are there any things to watch out for in this kind of setup? In other words, is there anything "more" to this code than a function which simply returns things by reference in order to avoid unnecessary copying operations?

Comment: Sorry I didn't spot that. This case is fine.

Comment: No, there's nothing more.  Infact it's done often with the << and >> operators

Comment: "*a function which simply returns things by reference in order to avoid unnecessary copying operations*" Is that the case here, or are you implying one would do this as an optimization? Because usually it is done for the semantics, not to prematurely optimize.

Comment: It's fine and done at other places. like @UKMonkey says done with the stream operators. e.g. here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt

Comment: It's very unclear whether you're really "avoiding unnecessary copies". The code is semantically *very* different from if you took and returned prvalues. I recommend to not think about "avoiding copies" so much, but rather consider this: References are a language feature that enable user-defined lvalues, i.e. functions whose call evaluates to lvalues. *That*'s how you tell whether you need to "return a reference". (Optimizations are more concerned with returning "const references".)

Comment: It is kind of weird why you return the variable. If you modify it inside your function you don't need to return it because it is already modified by just being a reference. But there may be circumstances this is needed.

Comment: this code is similar to standard operator << for std::ostream. so this is normal way to code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Except the obvious pitfall of returning a reference to a local
>   variable of the function (which is not the case here), are there any
>   things to watch out for in this kind of setup?

No, not really, it's perfectly valid but it has no advantage either. (in the current state of `myFunction`)

> in order to avoid unnecessary copying operations?

There's still a copy being made here:

```
int x;
int y = 10;
x = myFunction(y); // value of y is copied to x.
```

This is less readable and doesn't speed up anything when it comes to just normal initialization:

```
int x;
int y = 10;
x = y;
```

There's no reason to do this in this situation, just stick to normal initialization.

Of course, if `myFunction` adds some kind of modification to a more complex object than `int&` then you can take advantage of returning the reference as you can then:

```
chain.method().calls();
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, of course myFunction() is useless as it is in my sample code. I was just giving a minimum example that we can talk about.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided works because you're passing the variable to your function by reference, and still returning it by reference. This is consistent and works, but is weird. Why would you return the same variable that you're passing by reference? (I just remembered from the comments that this is useful for chaining in std::ostream, for example.)

On the other hand, if you pass that variable by value, you'll have a dangling reference and it won't work. So this **won't work**:

```
int & myFunction(int input) {
    return input;
}
```

In my opinion, the only return by reference I find appropriate is if you return a variable from inside a class's method. Besides that, I don't think you should return by reference at all.

You can *catch* a variable as a constant reference and avoid copying it if you want without having a dangling if you do this:

```
int myFunction(int input) {
    return input;
}

int main()
{
    const int& myInt = myFunction();
    //myInt is still valid here
}
```

This is a special case that.

Comment: I mean the first part is done in the stl itself. and about the pass by value. It is stated in the question that OP is aware about this.

Comment: Thanks, I'm asking about this specific case though(i.e. we are not wrongly returning a reference to a local variable). Is there anything "more" to this scenario?

Comment: @space_voyager I don't see why you would ever do that. It's very ambiguous and unreadable to pass by reference and return the same variable by reference...

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist it's perfectly readable; infact it HELPS readability!  Let's look at 
cout << foo << bar << baz;  what do you think << is returning to be used like this?  It's also done in builder pattern.   foo().setActive().setBaz()

Comment: @UKMonkey Well, you're right. This is useful for chaining too. I forgot that.